# what does require("child_process") actually do?

Tags: node.js, child-process

When we call :

```
var p = require(child_process);
```

Are we already creating a *child process* ? (if not, what is the `p` here?)

To explain my confusion futher, in a codebase i picked up, i see :

```
var childProcess1 = require("child_process");
var  _retrieveChild = childProcess1.fork(
           __dirname + '/backgroundProcesses/DadProcess',
           { execArgv: ['--debug=5859'] }
        );
```

I am asking myself whether it is creating yet another process from a child process or is the `childProcess1` just a badly chosed name?

Comment: `require` resolves a module; in this case `child_process` http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id

Comment: Thanks! and then I have to say, child_process is a poor choice of name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Requiring modules *can* sometimes initialize the module, so don't feel bad about not knowing. They are all different. However, `child_process` does **not** create a process simply by requiring the module as you have done. You have to call either [`fork()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) or [`spawn()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) (or `exec()`) to actually create a new process (and PID).

If you look at the documentation you can see how sometimes they will use this syntax:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
// ...
spawn('ps', ['ax']);
```

which basically grabs the module API, then the `spawn` method off of that and aliases it to a local variable for use later in the code.

*EDIT*

Just to expand on this for your understanding generally, inside of a Node module, the module decides what to "export". Whatever it exports is what will be returned from the `require(...)` call. For example, if we had this module:

```
// foo.js
module.exports = function() {
    return "bar";
};
```

Then `require("foo")` would give us a function (but it would not have been called yet):

```
var mymodule = require("foo");
var result = mymodule(); // <-- this calls the function returned via module.exports
console.log(result); // "bar"
```

Comment: nice explanation sir.Can u give the solution how to use child process in my daily used API like get the data from mongo or read uploads the images?

Answer (score 3):

The [`child_process` module](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) acts as a namespace for the [`spawn`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), [`exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), [`execFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback), and [`fork`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) functions. You call `require("child_process")` to refer to the module, and then call one of its member functions to create a new process.

The return value of each of those functions is a [`ChildProcess` object](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess), which represents the spawned process and has members like `stdin`, `stdout`, and `pid`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in doubt what it does, check what it returns.

```
var childProcess = require('child_process')
console.log(childProcess);
```

And you may get like this (depends on Node.js version):

```
{ ChildProcess: 
   { [Function: ChildProcess]
     super_: 
      { [Function: EventEmitter]
        EventEmitter: [Circular],
        usingDomains: false,
        defaultMaxListeners: 10,
        init: [Function],
        listenerCount: [Function] } },
  fork: [Function],
  _forkChild: [Function],
  exec: [Function],
  execFile: [Function],
  spawn: [Function],
  spawnSync: [Function: spawnSync],
  execFileSync: [Function: execFileSync],
  execSync: [Function: execSync] }
```

The latest node version [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) for ChildProcess.